# CreateJS: poor/strange framerate in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, createjs, easeljs

I'm at the early stage of building my own game framework, based on CreateJS (especially on the feature of exporting everything from Flash IDE). And found out that framerate of CreateJS (EaselJS) is much worse in Firefox than in Chrome/IE.

Also, it seems that the framerate of app (which might be changed using Ticker.setFPS) doens't matter. It looks like Firefox has some problems with rendering (I've tried to use 60fps and 30fps, and in both cases there were problems, it looks like FF doesn't have any stable time/logic of rendering).

I've tried to play with Ticker.timingMode (set it to Ticker.RAF_SYNCHED), but it didn't help either.

And also, I've found a lot of similar topics/questions in the Internet, and no any clear answer.

So, I was wondering, if there is any way to improve framerate/rendering in FF or we should work with it as it is now?

P.S.: It looks like the problem, probably, partially might be on the CreateJS side, because I've found few nice HTML5 games (as I know they don't use CreateJS) with smooth and nice animations in FF. Here an example: https://www.netent.com/games/slots/dazzle-me/

Answer (score 2):

EaselJS just facilitates Canvas drawing operations and updates. I have built a number of applications and games without FireFox-specific performance issues using the CreateJS framework, so while there might be something that is happening *through* CreateJS causing the issue, it is more likely related to the content and how CreateJS is used.

Different browsers have different issues and performance differences, including how they handle vectors, large images on the GPU, etc. Without seeing code or an example, it is hard to pinpoint where the performance is going.

1. What have you tried so far to isolate the performance?
2. Do you have a lot of large images, text, or vector content?
3. Are you using filters or Shadows?
4. How are you determining that the framerate is not working? RAF_SYNCHED attempts to normalize the computer's RAF framerate (usually about 60 fps, but dependent on lots of things).
5. Do you have a lot of children (like particles) going on?
6. Are you checking mouse position or hitTesting often?

If you can provide more info, code samples, working demos, etc you can likely get a better diagnosis of what is happpening.

Comment: i would have loved to see this answer as a comment but I know you hadn't enough space... Still voting to close OP/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! And I'm sorry for not attaching link to the example. Here it is: http://www.boomstudio.ru/portfolio/files/others/html5/slottest/

Comment: > What have you tried so far to isolate the performance?
I've tried to create WebGL canvas for using SpriteStage and SpriteContainer, but it didn't help =(

> Do you have a lot of large images, text, or vector content?
I would say no. I don't have vectors or texts at the current stage at all. And I have many bitmap images, but they are not big (about 125x125 px)

> Are you using filters or Shadows? 
At the current stage, nope.

> How are you determining that the...
I'm not sure if it works or not. I'm just saying that using this feature doesn't change anything in a matter of framerate.

Comment: > Do you have a lot of children (like particles) going on?
I sort of have a lot of children (about 100-150 at the moment). Many of them are not visible (because of mask). There are about 20-30 children visible at the same time.

Comment: > Are you checking mouse position or hitTesting often?
Nope, at all.

Comment: If you open JS console in any of browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) you'll find messages about FPS. My current FPS data is:
FF: 49-59 (and it varies a lot, I think the main reason of "not smooth" rendering is a big variety for FPS).
IE: 57-59
Chrome: 58-60